# Sort whole store in paging grid extjs 4

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid, extjs4, paging

in my app I have a paging grid and when I click on a column to sort it, it sorts only the current page. How can I sort the whole store and then split it in pages?
Can I override the sort function to send extra params to the php script that convert my database into a json store and edit the query adding a `ORDER BY extraparam`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enable `remoteSort` by setting `remoteSort: true` on the store instance. See **[remoteSort](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteSort)**

You will now receive the sorting as you receive the paging as own params-list and can include it into your query.